# Is there a way to upsert dataframe in mongoDB?

Tags: pandas, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo, upsert

I have an existing data in MongoDB where Primary Key is set on 'date' with a few fields in it.

And I want to upsert a new pandas dataframe with same fields to the existing dataframe in MongoDB

for example, I have a df that looks like

[image]

and I want to upsert the df that looks like

[image]

so the dulicated indices 2017-05-19 21:19:00, 2017-05-19 21:20:00, 2017-05-19 21:21:00
are updated with new values, and other new indices are added to the existing df

So the final df should look like this

[image]

I'm currently using

```
    try:
        cursor.insert_many(data, ordered=False)
    except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as e:
        print(e.details['writeErrors'])
```

to do this, and this function works well on appending new indices, but throws

`'keyValue': {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 15, 9, 24)}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: bitcoin.raw index: date_1 dup key: { date: new Date(1597483440000) }'`

kind of error on duplicated indices.

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `insert_many()`. You will need to iterate the dataframe and use [`replace_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) for each record, with a filter matching the date and `upsert=True` set.

Use something like:

```
for row in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    db.mycollection.replace_one({'date': row.get('date')}, row, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much. You saved my day!